# Modifying existing pagelayout

Tags: administration, page-layout

How can I modify an existing page layout so that the page layout assigned to `managers` display

`Cases`
`Acitivity History`
`Notes and Attachments`
`Partners`

If the page layout is assigned to `sales rep` those above mentioned related lists should not be display . Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple layouts, such as Enterprise Edition or Professional Edition with Profiles, you can create two page layouts, and assign the "manager" layout to the manager profile, and the "sales user" payout to the sales user profile. This is done with the "page layout assignment" button on the object's page layout section. Each layout can have differing related lists.